# Jsonp not getting variable userRole

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a jsonp that pulls the content of a single variable - userRole off of a completely separate URL. I can only do javascript on the server URL, and the sites have to remain separate. Why does service.userRole return undefined? How do I fix it?
Server:

```
function service(request, response)
{
var callBackFuncStr = request.getParameter('callback');
var strJson='';
var jsonval = userRole;
strJson=callBackFuncStr+'(\''+jsonval+'\');';
response.write(strJson);
var json=userRole;
var context=  nlapiGetContext();
   var userRole = context.getRole();
   response.write( userRole); 
}
```

Client:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.ajax({
    url: "********.com/app/site",
    type: "GET",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success: function( service ) {
        console.log(service.userRole);
    },
    error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
  console.log( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
        console.log( "Status: " + status );
        console.dir( xhr );
    }, 
    // Code to run regardless of success or failure
    complete: function( xhr, status ) {
  console.log( "The request is complete!" );
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you set `userRole` on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your `service` function is messed up.

```
var callBackFuncStr = request.getParameter('callback');
// callBackFuncStr is now `callback716242`, or whatever jQuery
// said it will be
var strJson='';
// strJson is now an empty string
var jsonval = userRole;
// userRole is declared in the current function but not yet
// defined, so it will give you a value of `undefined`. Thus,
// `jsonval` also becomes `undefined`.
strJson=callBackFuncStr+'(\''+jsonval+'\');';
// The `strJson` now becomes "callback716242('undefined')".
// This would probably be wrong thing to do even if `jsonval`
// was correct in the first place.
response.write(strJson);
// You send `callback716242('undefined')` to the client.
// If this were all, the client would receive the string
// `"undefined"` as the JSONP response. Even if it was a valid
// user role, a string does not have a `.userRole` property.
// But that is not all...
var json=userRole;
// `json` is now also `undefined`.
var context=  nlapiGetContext();
   var userRole = context.getRole();
// Only now does `userRole` get a value (say, `admin`)
   response.write( userRole); 
// Now you write once more to the client; the client will now
// receive `callback716242('undefined')admin`, which should
// generate a JavaScript error. \o/
```

To fix this, let's rearrange your function a bit.

```
function service(request, response) {
  var callBackFuncStr = request.getParameter('callback');
  var context = nlapiGetContext();
  var userRole = context.getRole();                // "admin"
  var payload = { userRole: userRole };            // { userRole: "admin" }
  var json = JSON.stringify(payload);              // "{userRole:\"admin\"}"
  var jsonp = callBackFuncStr + "(" + json + ")";  // "callback716242({userRole:\"admin\"})"
  response.write(jsonp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I fought with this thing for days now trying to get it to work. Thank you for taking the time to describe what is going on too.  I have a long way to go in understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is just returning a single string, not an object with a `userRole` property. So it should be:

```
success: function(userRole) {
    console.log(userRole);
},
```

Or you can fix the server so it returns an object. It should do:

```
strJson=callBackFuncStr+'({"userRole": "'+jsonval+'"});';
```